# Fill in a ArrayList within a configuration jelly file for a Jenkins Plugin

Tags: list, plugins, jenkins, jelly

I have a problem when trying to implement the configuration file of my plugin.
I started my program with the already existing SideBar Plugin, but I encountered a problem when I added a `List<String>` as a variable to the `class Action` : `private List<String> projects;`
How can I fill such a list within the jelly file?

I tried doing as such :

```
<f:entry>
 <f:optionalBlock title="Project to be considered :">
  <f:repeatable var="project" items="${link.projects}" name="projects" add="Add a project">
   <f:entry title="Project 1 :">
   </f:entry>
  </f:repeatable>      
 </f:optionalBlock>
</f:entry>
```

I added these lines in the links.jelly file, but it doesn't work.

If anyone knows how to do this, it would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The list in your action should have a type (also for better reading)

```
private List<YourObject> projects
```

Then your config.jelly can look like this:

```
<f:repeatable var="projectInList" name="projects" items="${instance.projects}" noAddButton="true" minimum="0">
    <fieldset>
        <f:entry title="${%Project}" description="Project desc." 
                                field="variableInProjectObject">
            <f:textbox value="${projectInList.variableInProjectObject}" default="" />
        </f:entry>
    </fieldset>
</f:repeatable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed similar problem this way:

```
<f:entry title="Parameters" field="projects">
   <f:repeatableProperty field="projects"  minimum="1" />  
</f:entry>
```

Thanks to [this resource](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Repeatable-set-of-fields-td4652233.html)